# error while loading shared libraries libSDL-1.2.so.0

Tags: 12.04, bash, shared-library

I am trying to install ioquake on my ubuntu server.

When I try to run it, I get this message:

```
# ./ioquake3
./ioquake3.x86_64: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I thought I had everything working right, here is where the libSDL is:

```
# cd /usr/lib64
# /usr/lib64# ls -l
total 2308
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Oct 15 00:25 libSDL-1.1.so.0 -> libSDL-1.2.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Oct 15 00:25 libSDL-1.2.so.0 -> libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2358903 Jan 19  2012 libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
```

And my path:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that this is a message *from* libSDL rather than about libSDL. Run `strace ./ioquake.x86_64`. This will show all system calls (takes way more time to execute). It will show which attempt to open which file will fail.

Comment: I installed trace. When I run it straight up, I get the help. When I run strace ./ioquake.x86_64 as you suggested I get  command not found. I'm getting a headache :(

Comment: I installed strace*

Comment: From the [OpenArena FAQ](http://openarena.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ), this message appears when libSDL isn't installed, so I don't think it came _from_ it. Not the best idea, but just to be sure, have you tried to rename libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4 into libSDL-1.2.so.0 ?

Comment: even if the first worked for you: please mark the second (23 upvotes) as answer as it is actually right for 99% of people.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsdl1.2debian
```

Post any error messages you might see

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me:

`sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386`

Comment: this is the better answer this should be marked as answer.

Comment: The current chosen answer tells us to `apt update` and `apt reinstall`, but you don't need any of that, all you need is to install the i386 architecture of libsdl. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: I needed to install libsdl1.2debian, not libsdl1.2debian:i386, in order to get OpenArena to open in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Note that `i386` is for 32-bit, so you don't need it for 64-bit machine - meaning you can just do `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian`

Comment: @tsveti_iko well it's been a few years, maybe ioquake needed the 32 bit version even on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Thanks, I needed the 32-bit version for apps such as Deflemask, and the error message didn't make it clear. Maybe running `file my_executable` would allow spotting 32-bit executables in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year late. But this should fix it:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian
```

The problem is that you are running a program compiled for a 32 bit architecture with 64 bit libraries.

Comment: Alternatively `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386`

Comment: @Joril I think your comment should be an answer as itself

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
```

Comment: May you include some explanation on what the problem is and how running the above command would solve it?

Comment: actually the user applications uses the above library inorder to dump text or images on to the SDL window

Comment: I mean include explanation in the answer. Yet, I think this explanation is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still relevant to Ubuntu 14.04 for old but still in use programs such as GCCG (Generic Collectible Card Game).

There are two very large answers on the subject:

1. [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit/454254#454254)
2. [How to install ia32-libs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr)

Answer (score 0):

No one else's answer solved this for me. This did though:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libopenal1 libsndfile1 libncursesw5
```

Something to do with 64 bit dependencies not being installed due to 32 bit libraries, I'm not sure.