# Couldnt find a way to open blender software

Tags: executable, blender

I am new to Ubuntu. I downloaded the latest version of Blender (2.70a) from official blender.org site as an tar.bz2 file. My Ubuntu OS is 14.04 LTS amd64 bit os, and I am sure that I have downloaded the correct version of blender. I have read that for security reasons, Ubuntu does not allow executing exe files.

Since the downloaded package contains blender as an executable/x-executable type, it is not able to execute. I do not have an internet connection in that computer too.
Also the "Allow executing file as program" checkbox is checked by default.
Still double clicking it does not execute the file.
Can anyone say how to open this file?

P.S: Wine also checked but requires active internet connection, which I dont have.

Comment: Sir, I read this page previously before asking this question. I found the link you gave while querying google, but it does not picture the answer of my problem, sir
I tried that too, but couldnt find the solution

Comment: I have just downloaded the package (32 bit though) and double clicking the 'blender' executable package. Open up your terminal and drag the blender package to it. Remove the single quotes and the space at the end and press enter. Edit your question and include any errors that will be displayed in the terminal.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376760/can-not-properly-install-blender/376802#376802) about how to install Blender in Ubuntu 14.04 together with the CUDA runtime library. All the latest Blender features including an up-to-date version of Blender, the Cycles rendering engine and the CUDA runtime library can all be installed using the Ubuntu Software Center. To install without an internet connection: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline).

Comment: Don't install the Nvidia driver or the CUDA runtime library unless your computer has an Nvidia GPU.

Comment: @Parto Do you mean the tar.bz2 package or the extracted one
So i think however ubuntu compulsorily requires internet for installing softwares..
So there is no way to download packages via a windows platform and then install in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto the download page of blender and select whether you want the 32bit or 64bit versions. Download it - let's assume to your Desktop. It will be a tar.bz2 package.

[image]

Right click on it and select 'Extract here'. You can also open it first in the archive manager and extract from there. You will get these files:

[image]

To run blender, double click on the blender file - highlighted above.

Another way would be to open up the terminal and run it directly:

```
~/Desktop/blender-2.70a-linux-glibc211-i686/blender
```

[image]

Comment: The step you told to execute blender is where i am getting trapped. Thats the point of my problem. When I double click it, NOTHING HAPPENS. 
When dragged to terminal, removed the single quotes and pressed enter, I received the following error message:
"Error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0:cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory "

Comment: Look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/201202/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsdl-1-2-so-0

Comment: Thank you sir, Finally I was able to run Blender. It was missing a dependency file, which when downloaded and installed, made it run

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy blending.